# Disable REST Service in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver

Is it possible to disable the REST service entirely for GeoServer? I.e have nothing exposed at http://..../geoserver/rest?

If so, how? and will it have any detrimental implications for clients e.g. QGIS?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can disable it, but it won't affect your QGIS users

Comment: Thanks Ian, I didn't think so either. It just puzzles me that it can't be turned off easily, and I thought maybe there's a reason for that...

Comment: It's very useful and no one has needed to turn it off yet, This is your chance to improve the project to support your use case - https://geoserver.org/devel/

Comment: Yeah well... I worry it reveals too much info about my setup, For example it exposes the root-address of my server residing behind the reverse proxy. It seems I can only avoid that by configuring a Global Proxy-Base-URL - and I'm not sure that I'm interested in that. As for me contributing to the geoserver-project, I'm not sure the rest of the world is interested in that ;-)

Comment: So don't reverse proxy any URL including `/rest/`

Comment: Yes that seems to be the easiest solution. Unfortunately I'm not in control of our gateway, so I'll have to send that task upstream. Thanks again :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default configuration only allows access for admins ($data_dir/security/rest.properties):

```
/**;GET=ADMIN
/**;POST,DELETE,PUT=ADMIN
```

If you don´t even trust your admins you can assign rights to a group that does not exist:

```
/**;GET,POST,DELETE,PUT=NON_EXISTING_GROUP
```

What you can't do is remove all access rules, that would allow anyone!

Or if you are behind a reverse proxy, just don't proxy /rest as Ian pointed out.

Comment: Thanks, I went with Ian's suggestion, but I'll keep your advise in mind.